# C++ register pattern with static member works "sometimes"

Tags: c++, static, linkage

I am trying to implement automatic class registration at runtime (I think this technique goes under the name of "register pattern"). In the following example I am storing an `int` in a static member vector, but the goal would be to store function pointers that can be called later.
My understanding is that, since the member `registeredClasses` in my code below is declared `static`, there should be only one instance of it throughout the program. However this seems not to be the case:

classregister.h

```
#ifndef CLASSREGISTER_H
#define CLASSREGISTER_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class ClassRegister
{
public:
    static std::vector<int> registeredClasses; //declaration

    ClassRegister(int id) {
        std::cerr << "registering " << id << " ";
        registeredClasses.push_back(id);
        std::cerr << "new size: " << registeredClasses.size() << "\n";
    }

    //code below just for testing
    ClassRegister() {}

    static int getSize() {
        return registeredClasses.size();
    }
};

#define REGISTER_CLASS(cls) \
    static ClassRegister myClass_##cls(1);

#endif // CLASSREGISTER_H
```

classregister.cpp

```
#include "classregister.h"

std::vector<int> ClassRegister::registeredClasses; //definition
```

class1.h (class2.h follows the same pattern, omitted for brevity)

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H

#include "classregister.h"

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
};

REGISTER_CLASS(Class1)

#endif // CLASS1_H
```

class1.cpp (class2.cpp follows the same pattern, omitted for brevity)

```
#include "class1.h"

Class1::Class1()
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "classregister.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cerr << "registering classes works...\n\n";

    std::cerr << "but reading from main() does not...\n";
    std::cerr << "checking size directly: " << ClassRegister::registeredClasses.size() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "checking size through function: " << ClassRegister::getSize() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "checking size on instance: " << ClassRegister().getSize() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "\n";

    std::cerr << "registration from main() uses a different register...\n";
    ClassRegister(2);
    ClassRegister(3);
    ClassRegister(4);
    std::cerr << "\n";

    std::cerr << "...which is not the one used in the header files\n";
    std::cerr << "checking size directly: " << ClassRegister::registeredClasses.size() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "checking size on instance: " << ClassRegister().getSize() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "checking size through function: " << ClassRegister::getSize() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "\n";
}
```

The issue I have is that it works only "sometimes". Initial output:

```
registering 1 new size: 1
registering 1 new size: 2
registering classes works...

but reading from main() does not...
checking size directly: 0
checking size through function: 0
checking size on instance: 0

registration from main() uses a different register...
registering 2 new size: 1
registering 3 new size: 2
registering 4 new size: 3

...which is not the one used in the header files
checking size directly: 3
checking size on instance: 3
checking size through function: 3
```

I removed class1.cpp and class2.cpp, declaring the constructors in the header files, eg. `Class1() {}`. Regsitration did not work at all:

```
//no output here
registering classes works...
//...
```

Then I reverted the change and suddenly I get the expected output:

```
registering 1 new size: 1
registering 1 new size: 2
registering classes works...

but reading from main() does not... //it does work this time
checking size directly: 2
checking size through function: 2
checking size on instance: 2

registration from main() uses a different register...
registering 2 new size: 3
registering 3 new size: 4
registering 4 new size: 5

...which is not the one used in the header files
checking size directly: 5
checking size on instance: 5
checking size through function: 5
```

I have been researching on this issue, but failed to understand the cause. My guess is that it has something to do with the compilation order (but how does registration work then?) or with [linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) / [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: One idea that comes to mind is the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: I actually read that FAQ during my research, but I thought it does not explain the observed behaviour for two reasons: (a) I thought (correct me if I am wrong) that static initialization is guaranteed to occur before main() is entered; and (b) even if the previous assumption is false, and we are indeed dealing with the "static init fiasco", then the two first lines in the output seem to confirm that we are in the "lucky" case where the vector is written to _before_ and read _after_. Moreover, with the "fiasco" I should get a crash, should I not?

Comment: Yes, static initialization will happen before `main()`, but so will your REGISTER_CLASS macro calls. Bam, fiasco. And no, the fiasco will not necessarily cause a crash. It is undefined behavior. More likely, you will get much more subtle, spooky problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the trick you need here is in `ClassRegister` instead of a static data member, use a function with a static local. This is sometimes called a singleton, although I don't know if that is really the correct term for it.

Code would probably look like:

```
typedef std::vector<int> register_type;
register_type& getRegister() {
    static register_type registeredClasses; //declaration
    return registeredClasses;
}
```

Comment: The C++ FAQ calls this the [Construct On First Use Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use). And there are risks to using a static local instance: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#construct-on-first-use-v2

Comment: This solution works. We are indeed observing a case of [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order), although with different effects from the one described by the C++ FAQ. As Fred Larson points out, the solution in the accepted answer by Zan Lynx is the [Construct On First Use Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#construct-on-first-use-v2), or better its variation using a static object. The FAQ explains the risks of using this variation, but these do not apply to my use case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you implement automatic class registration scheme, you should be careful about static initialization order, multi-threading.

The reason it didn't work when you removed .cpp files is because the header files are not compiled and therefore no one knows there were any declarations.